# Gulp browserSync runs 1 change behind

Tags: sass, gulp, browser-sync

I'm trying to setup Gulp browserSync for our development environment at work and I've got it working, but when I change something in sass for the first time, it doesn't refresh. But when I change it again, then it does work but it changes to the adjustment of the fist change. So it kinda has a delay of one change

This is my Gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

gulp.task('browserSync', ['sass'], function() {
  browserSync.init({
    proxy: "develop.work.dev"
  });
});

gulp.task('sass', function() {
  return gulp.src("themes/comp-fluid/sass/**/*.scss")
          .pipe(sass())
          .pipe(gulp.dest("themes/comp-fluid/css"))
          .pipe(browserSync.reload({
            stream: true
  }));
});

gulp.task('watch', ['browserSync', 'sass'], function(){
  gulp.watch('themes/comp-fluid/sass/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
  gulp.watch('themes/comp-fluid/views/**/*.tpl').on('change', browserSync.reload);
});
```